# Cannot login to Office account within workgroups/domains

Tags: authentication, synchronization, ms-office, onenote

Microsoft Support tells me that I cannot login to my office account to sync with OneDrive, download an Word template etc, if my computer is part of a Workgroup or a Domain! I am using OneNote, but I cannot sync it with OneDrive to share the documents with all my devices. Yes, If I exit from my Workgroup, I can login to my Office account and sync with all my devices.  There must be a solution. It cannot be an either/or case. Many organizations are either in a domain or workgroup environment and use Office (like Office365). Can't they login to their Office accounts out of their domains?

Comment: To where are you trying to add the account? You should be able to add one under Settings => Accounts => Email and App Accounts assuming you're on Win10.

Comment: Also there is a Group Policy Option that your system administrator can set to prohibit you from adding MSAs to your account. This is an explicit decision made by your IT department. See this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715259.aspx

Comment: Although I can easily login to my Office account from any browser, I cannot do the same from the same computer when I try to sign in from any Office program (Word, OneNote, etc.), I get "We are unable to connect right now, Please check your network and try it again" message. Since I cannot sign in to my Office account like OneDrive, I cannot sync, and share my OneNote entries among my devices.  MS says that this is because my computer is part of a workgroup! I believe there must be another reason because many companies which maintain their computers in a workgroup/domain and use Office 2016.

Comment: If you open OneNote and go to File=>Accounts, do you see "Add a Service?" Can you click on OneDrive?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: VPN. I have a VPN link to my router at home. If that is on, I cannot login to my Office account from any Office program, although I can easily login from a web browser on the same computer. I am not sure if this is by design or a bug, but the solution is simple, if I want to synchronize my OneNote notes with my devices, I just stop the VPN. Four help sessions with MS support did not give me even a hint!